Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x7d8646d22b00>
i was training a dataset with a model like this
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=2e-5)

# Compile the model (using optimizer)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# Train the model
model.fit(train_inputs, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

and it returns this error:
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x7d86540b1810>
optimizer.adam but it does not work correctly

Import "tensorflow.keras.optimizers" could not be resolved

Did you mix tensorflow.keras and keras imports like the answers to this question suggest?
